# Pandas Dataframe Python: Code BugFix and Simplification - 50% of Space reduction at Store-Category Level if Location='Y'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, debugging

**Input Explained:** Having a Dataframe `df` with columns as mentioned below:

```
Store   Category    Space   Location
11      AA          2.0     Y
11      BB          1.5     Y
11      CC          3.0     N
12      AA          4.2     Y
```

and got a variable `'Location_Percentage = 0.5'`(50%)

**Scenario:** For each Store, the Space column value of each Category with Location value as 'Y' has to be divided by the given 'Location_Percentage'. Include an additional column 'Reduced' if that particular Store-Category's Space value is reduced.

**Expected Output:**

```
Store   Category    Space   Location    Reduced
11      AA          1.0     Y           Y
11      BB          0.75    Y           Y
11      CC          3.0     N           N
12      AA          2.1     Y           Y
```

**Tried Code:** This is not working as expected. Also, need simplified approach for the scenario without much for/if loops.

```
loc_perc = 0.5
Store = 'Store'
Category = 'Category'
Location = 'Location'
Space = 'Space'

for i in dfOutput[Store].unique().tolist():

    dfNew = dfOutput[dfOutput[Store] == i].copy()
    dual_flows = dfNew[Category][dfNew[Location] == 'Y'].unique()
    
    for flow in dual_flows.tolist():
        
        if flow in dfNew[Category].values:
        
            original_space = dfNew[Space][dfNew[Category] == flow]
            reduced_space = original_space * loc_perc
            dfNew[Space] = reduced_space
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a temporary column to hold the current values of Space, compute the new values based on `Location` and `Space`, and finally create a new column `Reduced`, if the values in `Space` indeed are reduced.

You can think of `numpy where` as an if-else statement.

```
loc_perc = 0.5

df.assign(
    temp=lambda x: x.Space,
    Space=lambda x: np.where(x.Location == "Y", x.Space * loc_perc, x.Space),
    Reduced=lambda x: np.where(x.Space < x.temp, "Y", "N"),
).drop("temp", 1)



  Store Category    Space   Location    Reduced
0   11      AA      1.00        Y       Y
1   11      BB      0.75        Y       Y
2   11      CC      3.00        N       N
3   12      AA      2.10        Y       Y
```

Comment: Cool! This works perfect and Simple. Thanks for your time and help @sammywemmy